# Signing a PDF with an eID using PKCS#11 and iText

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

After following the "Signing a document using a smart card and PKCS#11" topic in http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures and creating a code sample similar to the provided one, the signed file signature is invalid in Adobe Reader, the signature appearance has the name of the non-repudiation certificate (i.e., the name of the eID owner) but in Adobe Reader's Signature Panel shows:

[image: Signed by Unknown]

The error occured while validating:
[image: Error message]

I'm using a **Gemalto PinPad** and the **Portuguese eID** `pteidpkcs11.dll` installed with the eID middleware software, located in C:\Windows\System32.

I've tried:

- Null checking
- Manually creating the Certificate chain, as the Certificate[] returned by  `ks.getCertificateChain("CITIZEN SIGNATURE CERTIFICATE");` only has the signature certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided code sample tries to get the `PrivateKey` of the signature certificate, I found it odd but figured it was just used as a reference. Navigating through the stack trace of the exception that is triggered when the user cancels the process in the PinPad gave me the following idea, which, fortunately, solved this:

1. Create a custom `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalSignature` implementation
2. Implement an utility class that, using the `sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11` wrapper, interacts with your eID pkcs11 dll (in my case, **pteidpkcs11.dll**) and provides a signing method that receives a byte[] message which is then sent to the SmartCard reader to be signed, and returns the byte[] result of this operation
3. Use the utility class in your CustomExternalSignature.sign(...)

Some tips that you can use if you're developing for the Portuguese eID *Cartão Cidadão*:

- For the second item of the previous list, I'm using the `PTeID4JPKCS11` class from an opensource project named [**pteid4j**](https://github.com/andremanuelbarbosa/pteid4j) created by André Barbosa, you just need to call `PTeID4JPKCS11.getInstance().sign(...);`
- Regarding the *Hash* and *Encryption* algorithm required by the `ExternalSignature` interface, the hash is **SHA-1** and the Encryption **RSA**

Comment: I am trying to do the same things. I have had a lot of problems but am able to (at least) run the code by Andre Barbosa by reverting the itextpdf version to 5.1.3. However, i really have no idea whatsoever what to do now. I will try to do a custom ExternalSignature implementation tomorrow!

Comment: How do you set a custom ExternalSignature using PdfSignatureAppearance.setExternalDigest(digest,data,algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you can sign with the portuguese eid card (Cartão de Cidadão) using only a java component available on [www.poreid.org](http://www.poreid.org). It is also available on maven central repository with the artifactid poreid

Here is an example based on the sample provided in the [itext documentation](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=222)

```
public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Assinado com o Cartão de Cidadão!"));
    document.close();
}

public void signPdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(POReIDConfig.POREID);
    ks.load(null);
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(POReIDConfig.AUTENTICACAO, null);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(POReIDConfig.AUTENTICACAO);

    // reader and stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');

    // appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper .getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason("qualquer motivo");
    appearance.setLocation("qualquer localização");
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72, 732, 144, 780), 1, "primeira assinatura");

    // digital signature
    ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", POReIDConfig.POREID);
    ExternalDigest digest = new ProviderDigest(null); // find provider
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Security.addProvider(new POReIDProvider());

    App exemplo = new App();
    exemplo.createPdf("/home/quim/exemplo.pdf");
    exemplo.signPdf("/home/quim/exemplo.pdf","/home/quim/exemplo.assinado.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on digital signature for PDF documents using Portuguese citizen card, and here is what I have:

```
public void signCAdES(...) {
    String pkcs11Config = "name=GemPC" + "\n" + "library=C:\\WINDOWS\\SysWOW64\\pteidpkcs11.dll";
    ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
    Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configStream);

    //provider_name: SunPKCS11-GemPC
    Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);

    javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler cmdLineHdlr = new DialogCallbackHandler();

    KeyStore.Builder builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", pkcs11Provider,
            new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(cmdLineHdlr));
    KeyStore ks= builder.getKeyStore();

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);

    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', new File(tempPath), true);
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();

    appearance.setReason(reason);
    appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setCertificationLevel(level);

    String alias = "CITIZEN SIGNATURE CERTIFICATE";

    //certificates from electronic card and resources folder
    Certificate[] certs = getSignatureCertificatesChain(ks);

    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, null);

    ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-1", pkcs11Provider.getName());
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, certs, null, null, null, 0, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CADES);
}
```

I have to build the certificates chain (**getSignatureCertificatesChain(ks)**) too since **ks.getCertificateChain("CITIZEN SIGNATURE CERTIFICATE")** only gives one certificate, and then the card itself doesn't have all the certificates so I have to get the missing ones at **pki.cartaodecidadao.pt** website and put them in a resources folder. Basically, I build my chain using both certificates in the card and in the resources folder, by linking them with the values in **certificate.getIssuerX500Principal().getName()** and **certificate.getSubjecX500Principal().getName()** (different cards can have different certificates of the same types, since the validity can vary so in one same type there can be 004 or 008 for example).

From what I understood, itext support for CAdES (**MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CADES**) is more recent, but you need to use this since using MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS might result in a signature that does not satisfy all the standards for CAdES (for example, missing the **signing-certificate** attribute - see http://docbox.etsi.org/ESI/Open/Latest_Drafts/prEN-319122-1v003-CAdES-core-STABLE-DRAFT.pdf).

The only minor issue with this code thought, is that there might be some optional attributes missing. I have used a validator from this tool https://github.com/arhs/sd-dss and while the signature generated passes the validation, it still gives a warning that the attribute **issuer-serial** is missing. I've created a post in hope anyone knows how to include the attribute here: [CAdES Digital Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893902/cades-digital-signature)

Answer (score -2):

```
 ks.getCertificateChain("CITIZEN SIGNATURE CERTIFICATE")
```

should return the certificate chain.

Where I can find a working online tool?

Suggestion: Make a call to the organization responsible for the middleware and ask for support.